# Почему я получаю не все header'ы из функции?

Tags: php, apache, сервер, settings

Есть вот такой простой код:

```
$test = apache_request_headers();
var_dump($test);
die();
```

Я с помощью  curl  посылаю на этот код `POST` запрос, который содержит `header` под именем `Authorization`. Теперь вопрос: этот `header` не приходит. Посылая на локальный сервер - получаю, на удаленный сервер - нет. По всей видимости проблема в настройках сервера. Вот пример того, что я получаю в качестве ответа с удаленного сервера:

```
array(8) {
   ["Accept-Encoding"]=> string(13) "gzip, deflate" 
   ["Cache-Control"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" 
   ["Accept-Language"]=> string(2) "ru"   
   ["User-Agent"]=> string(118) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.5 Safari/600.5.17" 
   ["Connection"]=> string(5) "close" 
   ["Accept"]=> string(63)"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" 
   ["Host"]=> string(16) "mydomain" 
}
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Посмотри, что лежит в $_SERVER на этот счет. В apache2 (если я не ошибаюсь) модуль mod_headers способен изменять (в том числе и удалять) заголовки. Проверь конфиг apache2

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader , директива `RequestHeader unset` нигде в конфигах не встречается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990388/request-headers-bag-is-missing-authorization-header-in-symfony-2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```